# Can not post request ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to use ajax in my codeigniter but it does not work.

If I echo only text it works properly. But, what I want is to get fullname from text box and check some conditions in php.

Anyone know what is the problem?

```
function loaddata(){
  var name=$("#fullname").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'pages/login',
    data: {
      user_name : name
    },
    success: function (response) {
      alert(response);
    }
  });
}
```

This is my controller.

```
<?php
  class Pages extends CI_Controller{
    public function view($page = 'home'){
      if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
        show_404();
      }
      $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);
      $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    }
    public function login(){
      // $username = $this->input->post['username'];
      echo "Username".$_POST['user_name'];
    }

  }
```

Comment: what is output on `alert(response)`?

Comment: try this `echo "Username".$this->input->post('user_name');`

Comment: Put `console.log(name);` just after `var name=$("#fullname").val();` to see if you are getting that value correctly.

Comment: Is your Jquery function being called in the first place? Are you trying to submit a form with the name in it? Can you post your name input field with the rest of the form data, if it is a form?

Answer (score 0):

try catch your error because, we don't know what your error

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_ajax+method,
    type: type,
    dataType: dataType,
    data: data,
})
.done(function(data) {
    callback(data);
})
.fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete sending");
});
```